# Queued Build is not connecting to db as it uses domainName\computerName instead of domanName\username

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to queue a build in my own build definition. But the sql connection in my code throws an exception that `Login failed for user 'domainName\computerName$'` which is natural since it should have used `domainName\userAlias`.

My question is why is it using `domainName\computerName`, and how to make it use windows auth instead? Can some one please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the service account that the build service uses on the server(s) running your Build Agent(s).  It sounds like it's currently set to run as Network Service.

You can change it by firing up TFS Admin Console, and going to Build Configuration and changing the properties on the service:

[image: Build Service Config]